# How to open a Microsoft Works file

Tags: file-types, microsoft-works

Is there a way to open a Microsoft Works file without downloading a file-opening program?  Can anything in MS Office do it?

Comment: -1  If you just asked How can you open an MS Works file in MS Office, FINE.   If you asked how to open an MS Works file in any way, FINE.  But to ask how to open an ms works file without a downloaded file opening program, that is an inexplicably absurd criteria. OFfice is a file opening program just often  not downloaded but installed on CD..But it can be downloaded. IF you have something preinstalled it's probably downloadable. And yeah it's a file opening program. If you'd asked how to do it either a)natively or b)with MS OFFICE, then fine. But the question as it stands -1

Comment: @barlop I'm not sure why you are obfuscating "needs to be downloaded" with "can be downloaded."  Why is it so bothersome if I don't want to have to download something from the internet, and not have to worry about viruses or security (since I am not very well-versed in internet security, I don't know what to look for)?  Why is it so wild so ask if other MS programs, or some program that comes on a MS OS, would be able to handle another MS program?  I'm not looking for "specifically is never downloaded," and that isn't what my question says.  So what's weird about not wanting to download?

Comment: You write " if I don't want to have to download something from the internet, and not have to worry about viruses or security (since I am not very well-versed in internet security," <---- There's no need to worry about malware necessarily, as Microsoft have Windows and Office for Download from their official site.  And there are many legitimate websites for 3rd party software, and if you're able to ask a question here you are able to ask on any forum what is a legit site to download software to do this or that.  Or, how to do it natively if possible.

Comment: And if you're asking about software that you have installed but didn't download. Then how are we supposed to know what software you have installed but that you didn't download. (other than Windows and Office). So it makes more sense to ask a)natively b)in office.  And as a side note i'd mention that if you want, programs you can download(On a forum people will generally pounce on a link to a malware site), besides knowing of decent sites and how to navigate them.

Comment: @barlop I don't know why it upsets you so much that I left out the words "If I don't want."  But ok.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about in that last comment of yours(where you didn't even quote what you were replying to), and I don't think you know what i'm talking about, and the issue was the quality of the question, not other things you bring up, and not what you might think, but don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Office does not have native support for Microsoft Works.  Microsoft Works was discontinued in 2007 and they dropped support for it.

There is a Microsoft Works 6–9 File Converter available for [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12).  Im a bit surprised looking at the supported OSs and Office versions - it is very limited, but it *might* still work for you on a newer OS/Office version.

Comment: The Microsoft Works 6–9 File Converter do not work in Office 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office Word should be able to open newer Works Word Processor files by default. You can use the "Works 6 - 9 Document (*.wps)" file filter in the open dialog.

Microsoft Office Excel is a bit trickier. You won't be able to choose a file filter, but choosing "All files" and selecting a Works .xlr file should work fine, since the new version of Works Spreadsheet uses the same format as Excel.

Unfortunately, you're probably out of luck for Database, Calendar, and Portfolio. New Office applications lack compatibility with their formats. Furthermore, if you need to open files created with a very old version of Works, you probably won't be able to. There are some add-ins for Office for compatibility for *some* of the older formats, but none will offer you a complete solution.

Your best bet is to download a converter program for these.